# Manipulating bitfields in a bytes buffer with standard library only

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to set specific bitfields within DWORDs, where DWORD is 4 bytes taken at *offset* in a bytes *buffer*. I want to use only functions available in the Python3 standard library. I came up with this piece of code below (the example is for the case of 4 bitfields within the DWORD):

```
field1 = set_bitfield(31, 29, 0x07)  # bit field 31:29 = 0x07
field2 = set_bitfield(28, 23, 0x2E)  # bit field 28:23 = 0x2E
field3 = set_bitfield(22, 16, 0x0E)  # bit field 22:16 = 0x0E
field4 = set_bitfield(15, 0, 0x08)      # bit field 15:0  = 0x08
struct.pack_into("<L", buffer, offset, field1|field2|field3|field4)
```

where I also defined the trivial set_bitfield() function:

```
def set_bitfield(bit_high, bit_low, value):
    return (value << bit_low) & ((1 << (bit_high + 1)) - 1)
```

Can this be done better in terms of simplicity and performance?

Comment: As this code works and you only need advices on it, you could ask the question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

First example

```
import itertools

bit_fields = [(31, 29, 0x07), (28, 23, 0x2E), (22, 16, 0x0E), (15, 0, 0x08)]
z = 0
for i in itertools.starmap(set_bitfield, bit_fields):
    z |= i
```

Second one

```
import itertools
import operator
import functools

x = functools.reduce(operator.or_,
                     itertools.starmap(set_bitfield, bit_fields))
```

However not advisable according to the [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)

> Removed reduce(). Use functools.reduce() if you really need it; however, 99 percent of the time an explicit for loop is more readable.